# Organic texturing tips

Tags: texturing, uv

I've modeled a T-Rex, UV Unwrapped it and everything and I want to know how to create a Dinosaur like Skin texture and apply it to the model.

Texturing solid and non-organics is insanely easy compared to organic characters, where I only get seams, patterns and a whole bunch of other issues.

Best thing I can do to it, is paint it with flat colors, but as you expect it doesn't look good at all.

So what's the way of creating a good Dinosaur Skin Texture and applying it without causing issues?

Comment: try to find a royalties free lizard skin texture and then smooth out seams using the texture paint mode.